# How to catch escape key press event inside while loop in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am running a function inside an infinite loop in jquery. I want to exit loop when escape key is pressed. I am unable to do it. My loop is running infinitely. Below is what I've done till now:

```
var playLoop = function(){
    var myVar;
    var continueLoop = 1;
    while(continueLoop === 1){

        $(document).on("keyup",function(e){
            if(e.key==="Escape"){
                continueLoop = 0;
            }
            myVar = setInterval(addition,1000);

        });

    }
}
```

I want to stop running a function inside a loop i.e. eventually a loop when 'escape' key is pressed. What am I missing? How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `.setTimeout`, which you can cancel with`.clearTimeout` once you recognise a press of the escape key. The example below works.

Let me know if you needed something else.

```js
// Start your playLoop after document is ready
$(document).ready(function() {
  playLoop();
});


function playLoop() {

  // Append a dot so you know it's working
  $(".dots").append(".");

  // Set a new timeout to count down
  playLoopCountdown = setTimeout(playLoop, 1000);

}


// Attach escape key cancel
$(document).on("keyup", function(e) {

  if (e.key === "Escape") {

    // Stop playLoop
    clearTimeout(playLoopCountdown);

    // Tell user the timeout has been stopped
    $(".dots").append("STOPPED");

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>You need to click within this iframe for the escape keypress to be registered.</p>
<div class="dots"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it that way. If you tie up the main UI thread with an infinite loop, the thread can't process tasks from its task queue. Events (such as keypresses) come through as tasks in the task queue.

Separately: `on` **registers** an event handler. You only need to register the handler **once**.

If you need to "loop" while also processing events, you need to set up a series of asynchronous operations instead (`setTimeout`, `setInterval`, ...).